# Externally triggering FullCalendar's 'dayClick' method?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using Arshaw's FullCalendar and I'm looking to simulate a user clicking on a cell once the page has loaded. I'm trying to do this so I could potentially go to a URL such as `/Calendar/AddEvent` and the calendar will automatically open a dialog with my add event form in.

Take the following set up: ([Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/vb56M/))

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div id="calendar" data-year="2013" data-month="04" ></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        firstDay: 1,
        selectable: true,
        dayClick: function (start, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
                    alert('You clicked me!');
        }
    });
```

By default, the cell for today has the class `.fc-today` which I've tried to take advantage of by doing the following:

```
$('.fc-today').trigger('click');
```

This doesn't seem to work though. Is there anyway I could do something like

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('dayClick', date)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by externally triggering?   http://jsfiddle.net/vb56M/20/

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this issue in my usecase as well, and this is what I found works for me, after digging around in the fullcalendar source code. You need to manually create a `mousedown` and `mouseup` event (technically the `mouseup` is optional, but you can use it to reset the 'clicked' state of the `td`), which contains the coordinates of the X and Y position of the element you want to "click". Also important is the `which` parameter, which needs to be set to `1` so that it [passes the `isPrimaryMouseButton` check](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/blob/3a464732a77eac8999875525549d19be0c423d5f/src/util.js#L294).

With this in mind, the code would look like this (note I changed the `$('#click')` to use a `mousedown` event so that it only runs once):

```
$('#click').on('mousedown', function () { 
    var today = $('td.fc-today');
    var down = new $.Event("mousedown");
    var up = new $.Event("mouseup");
    down.which = up.which = 1;
    down.pageX = up.pageX = today.offset().left;
    down.pageY = up.pageY = today.offset().top;
    today.trigger(down);
    today.trigger(up); //this is optional if you just want the dayClick event, but running this allows you to reset the 'clicked' state of the <td>
});
```

Here is a working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/vyxte25r/

Comment: Good work! I had to add 1 to both left and top in order to avoid clicking on the wrong day anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery `trigger` event on `div` inside `td` with `fc-today` class:

```
 $('td.fc-today div').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately this doesn't work either. See my latest fiddle for an example http://jsfiddle.net/vb56M/5/. I've changed the background colour of the div at the same time to make sure that the selector is actually finding the right cell (it is).

Comment: did you try this in your app? (not in jsfiddle), when I run $('td.fc-today div').trigger('click').css('backgroundColor', 'red'); from firebug console in my app, the background was change

Comment: Yes I did, the background colour changed fine but the alert box that I had set to open on clicking a day did not appear. I only added the background colour change to see if jQuery was finding the right element

Comment: I think the problem may be caused by fullcalendar version or by the jsfiddle - in my app I use 1.5.4 and I added your code from jsfiddle and it work as expected - after clicked on link, background was change and alert was show

Comment: @LukaszKoziara confirmed - it's working in jsFiddle correctly

Comment: Does anyone found a solution that works with recent versions (2.x.x) of full calendar?

Answer (score 0):

Modifying Kevin's answer a bit worked for me. I needed to make the dayClick event accessible by keyboard. Adding the event listener to each cell using the dayRender method allows us to easily handle the dayClick event for each day. Here's how I accomplished it:

```
dayRender: function(date, cell) {
  // Allow keyboard to access and interact with calendar days
  $(cell).attr("tabindex", "0").on("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.which === 32 || e.which === 13) {
      var day = $(this);
      var down = new $.Event("mousedown");
      var up = new $.Event("mouseup");
      var eventParams = { which: 1, pageX: day.offset().left, pageY: day.offset().top };

      day.trigger($.extend(true, {}, down, eventParams));
      day.trigger($.extend(true, {}, up, eventParams));
    }
  });
}
```

Relevant documentation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/dayRender/