# Fullcalendar month view: Selecting a day/multiple days even when clicking on events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

So FullCalendar has the awesome `selectable: true` option which allows you to click and drag on a day or multiple days to highlight them.

The issue I've encountered is that when there are events present, you need to click part of the day square "around" the event in order to select the dates.  If you click on the events themselves, then the day-selection does not work because, as designed, `eventClick` is triggered instead of `dayClick`.

I'm implementing FullCalendar in a public-facing UI and want to keep things simple.  Events are used simply to display information, and I'd like to be able to highlight a day or multiple days (and fire the `select` callback) regardless of whether the user initiates the click on the event itself or on the day.  In other words, I suppose I want the events to be invisible to the mouse, and be able to highlight multiple days regardless of where the click happens on the day.

Is this possible?  Any thoughts on how to do it?

Visual example in case this is confusing:

Selecting the day requires clicking "around" the event:

[image]

If you click on the event, selecting multiple days isn't possible:

[image]

Let me know if any thoughts on how to accomplish this!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind the grid lines appearing over the cells (this is probably a problem given your examples that have centred text), you can achieve this by changing the `z-index` of the table that holds the calendar view:

```
.fc-border-separate {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

This will just place the table above the events, stopping the `eventClick` from firing, but as I said, the grid lines from the cells will actually show on top of the events, like so:

[image]

Comment: Interesting idea - thanks.  I'm playing around with it a bit and you're right - the gridlines do get in the way since my text is centered.  I can disable the gridlines, though that makes usability a bit rough (it's harder to see where events & days line up).  But this is a good start, and it does work.

Comment: I wonder whether it's possible to have the event itself (fc-event-inner) be behind the gridlines but the actual event text (fc-event-title) in front of the gridlines?  That may be an acceptable solution, since the click would have to be on the text exactly for it not to work, which is a smaller target than the whole event and may be OK.

Comment: One more small update:  I found a good usability compromise is to disable the vertical gridlines but keep the horizontal (non-conflicting) gridlines.  Still not 100%, but 90% :)

Comment: Another approach could be to catch the event click and fake a day click. I can't get a jsFiddle to even fire fullcalendar's `eventClick` method, but could be worth a try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816353/externally-triggering-fullcalendars-dayclick-method

Answer (score 0):

Hello Noah there is no easy work around this, because in Fullcalendar, from what i have learned the past few months, the table displays the calendar ( numbers in table cells ) and above that, the event layer so this means in order to do what you want ( and me also :P ) we need to "somehow" push the events behind the table and i don´t know if its possible. I have tried to mess around with the z-index propriety from css and all, but withput success.

In fullcalendar.js in the functions were the body of the calendar is made i have also tried to mess with it but unfortunaly with no success...