# How to trigger dayClick of fullcalendar automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar

```
$scope.uiConfig = {
  calendar:{
    height: 450,
    editable: true,
    header:{
      left: 'title',
      center: '',
      //right: 'today prev,next' commented by dps for not to display today button
      center: 'prev,next',
      right: ''
    },
    dayClick: function(view,jsEvent,date, allDay,event) {


      //if($scope.view=='agendaWeek')#fc-day fc-widget-content fc-M fc-past
      //{
              //console.log(view);


               if (jsEvent.target.classList.contains('progress-day-time')) {

              //$("div").removeClass("fc-content-skeleton");
              $(".fc-state-highlight").removeClass("fc-state-highlight");
              //console.log(jsEvent.target);
              $(jsEvent.target).addClass("fc-state-highlight");
               var day=new Date(view._d);

               DataDateFetch(view._d);
              }

    //}
            },
    eventClick: $scope.alertOnEventClick,
    eventDrop: $scope.alertOnDrop,
    eventResize: $scope.alertOnResize,
    eventRender: $scope.eventRender,
    eventAfterAllRender: $scope.eventAfterAllRender 
  }
};
```

and trying to trigger
`$("#span id").trigger("click");`

Comment: what is this `#span id`? I think, this isn't a jQuery object. Is `id` a selector or what?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/34193117/1414562

Comment: yes I have assign dynamically and by using that id iam trying to trigger it

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(':checkbox').click(function() {
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    alert('Checked');
  } else {}
}).click();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
  </form>
  
   
   
</body>
</html>
```

A little hint :)